# Two children with the same key … React (ionic), although keys are unique

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, map-function

I am using two map functions in two different React components with two different keys.
But I still get that annoying error.
Can somebody please help me

Error message: index.js:1 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, .$. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

My two map functions

```
<Stepper activeStep={activeStep} alternativeLabel className="Stepper" >
  {stepss.map((label) => (
    <Step key={label}>
      <StepLabel>{label}</StepLabel>
    </Step>
  ))}
</Stepper>


<Stepper activeStep={activeStep} alternativeLabel className="Stepper" >
  {stepss.map((labell) => (
    <Step key={labell}>
      <StepLabel>{labell}</StepLabel>
    </Step>
  ))}
</Stepper>
```

initializing steeps (thid component)

```
const steps = [
    { id: 'Häuser' },
    { id: 'Fläche' },
    { id: 'Wohnfläche' },
    { id: 'Postleizahl' },
    { id: 'Submit' },
    { id: 'design' }
]



const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        width: '100%',
    },
    backButton: {
        marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    instructions: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
        marginBottom: theme.spacing(1),
    },
}));


function getSteps() {
    return ['', '', '', '', ''];
}

function getStepContent(stepIndex) {
    switch (stepIndex) {
        case 0:
            return 'Select campaign settings...';
        case 1:
            return 'What is an ad group anyways?';
        case 2:
            return 'This is the bit I really care about!';
        default:
            return 'Unknown stepIndex';
    }
}




export const MultiStepFrom = () => {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const [activeStep, setActiveStep] = React.useState(0);
    const stepss = getSteps();


    const [formData, setForm] = useState(defualtData)
    const { step, navigation } = useStep({
        steps,
        initialStep: 0,
    })

    const props = { formData, setForm, navigation, stepss, activeStep, setActiveStep, classes }

    switch (step.id) {.....
```

Comment: Your code looks fine, so I suspect that the keys are indeed *not* unique ;)
Could you share the code initializing `stepss`?

Comment: FYI, react warning messages don't lie.

Comment: Yes of course, i have made an update

Comment: The value of `stepss` is `['', '', '', '', '']`, nothing unique here, they are all the same value.